# mysql query for selecting records of similar column values for two given values

Tags: mysql

```
id        | person  | cities travelled  | distance

----------+---------+-------------+-----------

1         | jack   | japan              | 8

2         | Joe    | florida            | 11 

3         | Joe    | california         | 215 

4         | Jane   | ghana              | 3

5         | Jane   | florida            | 8

6         | Joe    | jakarta            | 11 

7         | Joe    | california         | 215 

8         | Joe    | japan              | 3
```

For two given persons "jane" and "joe", i want to find common cities they traveled. what is the sql query for that. In this case we can see that common cities which both jane and joe have travelled is 'florida'. How can i find it with help of sql query?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `group by` and `having`:

```
select CitiesTravelled
from t
group by CitiesTravelled
having sum(person = 'Joe') > 0 and
       sum(person = 'Jane') > 0;
```

By putting the logic in the `having` clause, you can easily generalize the query.  Here is the version for Jane *or* Joe:

```
select CitiesTravelled
from t
group by CitiesTravelled
having sum(person = 'Joe') > 0 or
       sum(person = 'Jane') > 0;
```

Here is the version for cities travelled by Jane, Joe, and Jack:

```
select CitiesTravelled
from t
group by CitiesTravelled
having sum(person = 'Joe') > 0 and
       sum(person = 'Jane') > 0 and
       sum(person = 'Jack') > 0;
```

EDIT:

If you want to add distance travelled, you can change the `select` to something like:

```
select CitiesTravelled, min(DistanceTravelled)
select CitiesTravelled, avg(DistanceTravelled)
select CitiesTravelled, max(case when person = 'Jane' then DistanceTravelled end)
```

Comment: the problem is i am getting those cities travelled, but different records. so when i fetch the distance by doing select* of your query, i get different distance. Can't your query be customized to get also distance of first person from his city travelled

Answer (score 0):

```
select CitiesTravelled 
from t
where person = 'Joe'
and CitiesTravelled in (
   select CitiesTravelled
   from t
   where person = 'Jane'
);
```

or

```
select CitiesTravelled
from t t1
where person = 'Joe'
and exists (
  select t2.CitiesTravelled
  from t t2
  where t2.person = 'Jane'
  and  t2.CitiesTravelled = t1.CitiesTravelled
);
```